# What is this drag effect called and necessary actions to preform it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, touchesmoved, skspritenode

Well I'm kind of stuck right now on finding resource to perform this drag effect.
The effect does this:

- touch a SKSpriteNode and hold
- Then you drag to a location you want to move the SKSpriteNode
- Finally you release your hand gesture and the node will move in a straight line(In a line motion) to that location you desire moving at delayed speed so you can see it move when you release your finger.

Comment: Have a look at this post -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436988/drag-skspritenode-based-on-touch-location -- It may have some additional info you require

Comment: I may not be right but you can use UILongPressGestures to activate UIPanGesture which can help you to move the object

Comment: This could help .. http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

Comment: Amar thats not exactly what im looking for more of a dragging a invisible line to a location and release and then the object goes to the location you wanted to go. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know any name for the drag effect, but it is quite simple to implement. The following is a very basic implementation, and can be enhanced.

First, declare two instance variables in your scene

```
SKNode *selectedNode;
UITouch *currentTouch;
```

Then, you can implement the desired functionality using the touch delegates.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchPoint];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"whatevername"])
    {
        selectedNode = node;
        currentTouch = touch;
    }
}



-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch isEqual:currentTouch])
    {
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInNode:self];
        [selectedNode runAction:[SKAction moveTo:point duration:1.0]];
        //Also can calculate time based on distance to make the movement uniform.

        selectedNode = nil;
        currentTouch = nil;
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch isEqual:currentTouch])
    {
        selectedNode = nil;
        currentTouch = nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like it is going to a random location and you can not drag it to the place you touched end.kind of like this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcdClbW-_fE) but there is only one Sprite Image and the other is stacked on top and there is no image on it so when you drag it and touch ends it goes to the location you last touched. After you release you touch event. If that made sense.

Comment: From the video, it seems that you want to make an underlying sprite follow the one being dragged around.

Comment: yes but more of a drag to taget point, release, and then move to the destination with that delay movement code you have.